# Where in the AWS API can I set the sender id for sending SMS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to set the sender ID in my API call, but it is being ignored.
Where do I put it/what is the correct attribute name?
I am in the USA, Below are the two places I tried to set the sender id (I tried both **SenderID** and **DefaultSenderID**)

```
    $result = $SnSclient->SetSMSAttributes([
        'attributes' => [
            'DefaultSMSType' => 'Transactional',
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' =>'CompanyBrand'

        ],
    ]);
    var_dump($result);//this currently gives an error (method call, not the var_dump)

    $result = $SnSclient->publish([
        'Message' => $message,
        'PhoneNumber' => $phone,
        'SenderID' => 'CompanyBrand'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise that you use PHP, but I'm a Python person. Just for comparison, this code worked for me:

```py
import boto3

sns_client = boto3.client('sns')

response = sns_client.set_sms_attributes(
    attributes={
        'DefaultSenderID': 'Foo'
    }
)
print(response)

sns_client.publish(Message='Hello',PhoneNumber='+xxx')
```

I noticed that it didn't like having a Space in the `DefaultSenderID`.

`SenderID` is not a valid parameter in the `publish()` command. Nor does it seem to recognize it as a `MessageAttribute` within the `publish()` command.

Comment: Good enough - I am well versed in Python, should be very easy to translate.Is your answer specific to Australia?

Comment: I tested it in Australia, but it there is nothing specific to a particular country. Admittedly, things might vary by Telco and even phone OS.

Comment: :-( Seems like it is not supported in the US